# How to read json file in gitlab ci yaml and use if else command?

Tags: if-statement, gitlab, yaml, message

I have a yaml file and I have a respond for yaml file.Respond file have a message part.and I need if message is true return Job Succeed for yaml file if message writes wrong yaml file is not succeed

```
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Tools\Nuget\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe'
  SOLUTION_PATH: 'Textbox_ComboBox.sln'

stages:
  - build
  - job1
  - job2

before_script:
  - "cd Source"

build_job:
  stage: build
  except:
    - schedules
  script:
    - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore'
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" "$env:SOLUTION_PATH" /nologo /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug'

job1:
  stage: job1
  script:
    - 'curl adress1'
    -  -  if [ "$message" == "SAP transfer started. Please check in db" ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi


job2:
  stage: trigger_SAP_service
  when: delayed
  start_in: 5 minutes
  only:
    - schedules
  script:
    - 'curl adress2'
```

It is yaml file respond.It should be job succeed.Because respond message and if command message is same.

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
$ cd Source
$ curl adress1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   146    0   146    0     0    877      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   879
{"status":200,"message":"SAP transfer started. Please check in db","errorCode":0,"timestamp":"2019-10-04T07:59:58.436+0300","responseObject":null}$ if ( [ '$message' == 'SAP transfer started. Please check in db' ] ); then exit 0; else exit 1; fi
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `message` variable you use in your condition is empty.

You need to assign the curl response to your `message` variable :

```
message=$(curl -Ss adress1)
```

and then test the content of `$message`

Comment: It writes request method POST not supported.

Comment: should I wrote this in script? and should I use ' ' ?

Comment: remplace `- 'curl adress1'` by `- message=$(curl -Ss adress1)`

Comment: @NicolasPepinster Is it possible to analyze the content of a JSON file into GitLab yml file? And put some if-else condition on that data to sucess or fail the pipeline?